# Setting the background with an existing brush

Tags: wpf, xaml

Imagine I have this brush:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MySolidDarkBackground" Color="{DynamicResource DarkBackgroundColorTop}" />
```

How can I use this brush for a scrollviewer background but with a different opacity?

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
            <ScrollViewer.Background>
                < ??? >
            </ScrollViewer.Background>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd either have to create a second Brush resource and use it:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyTransparentDarkBackground" Opacity="0.5" Color="{DynamicResource DarkBackgroundColorTop}" />
<ScrollViewer Background="{DynamicResource MyTransparentDarkBackground}" />
```

Or you could just reuse the dynamic Color resource:

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <ScrollViewer.Background>
    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.5" Color="{DynamicResource DarkBackgroundColorTop}" />
  </ScrollViewer.Background>
</ScrollViewer>
```